# Microsoft Message Queue and ASPX

Tags: c#, msmq

I wrote a small app using MSMQ as a way to pass data from my app to another one, which is quite the purpose of MSMQ.

I also wrote a small aspx webpage that monitors the content of the msmq, and can be used to send messages into it.

For security reasons, I had to set the rights of the MSMQ to a user group, so that the first random can't delete the queue or empty it. 
However, this sadly removed the rights of my app to write anything.

Would anyone have a clue as to what user group an aspx webpage is part of?

Even though I don't work with NserviceBus, I've tried the advice given here : http://blog.jonathanoliver.com/nservicebus-asp-net-permissions-for-msmq/ by giving Network Service **getproperties**, **peek**, **receive** and **send** rights, but it wasn't enough.

I might add code if requested but it doesn't seem necessary here since it's mostly GUI use.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Your app pool in IIS is probably running as ApplicationPoolIdentity. You could create or use a Windows domain account to run the app pool. Or you could change it to Network Service if you want.

Comment: That's right. If you comment I'll take your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app pool in IIS is probably running as ApplicationPoolIdentity. You could create or use a Windows domain account to run the app pool. Or you could change it to Network Service if you want

Comment: I... accept your answer even if my reputation is too low ;'( weird thing stack overflow.

To be complete, I indeed had to change the identity of my application pool but it worked perfectly after.